# Problem with adding a dropout layer, Layer spatial_dropout1d_5 was called with an input that isn't a symbolic tensor?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

So I am using GloVe word embeddings

```
emb = Glove(emb_filename)
word_embedding_layer = emb.get_keras_embedding(#dropout = 0.5,
                                            trainable = True,
                                            input_length = sent_maxlen, 
                                           name='word_embedding_layer')
```

I commented dropout since I got a warning that its no longer supported in Keras and I should use **spatialDropout1d** instead and that's what I did

```
word_embedding_layer = keras.layers.SpatialDropout1D(0.5)(word_embedding_layer)
```

However I am getting this error and I don't know how to fix my input to make it a tensor

```
 ValueError: Layer spatial_dropout1d_5 was called with an input that isn't a symbolic tensor. Received type: <class 'keras.layers.embeddings.Embedding'>. Full input: [<keras.layers.embeddings.Embedding object at 0x7f4a42989358>]. All inputs to the layer should be tensors.
```

Comment: You are giving a layer as input to Dropout, which should be the output of the previous layer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`word_embedding_layer` is a layer.

You must give a "tensor" to the layers.

```
input_tensor = Input(some_shape)
embedding_tensor = word_embedding_layer(input_tensor)
dropout_output = keras.layers.SpatialDropout1D(0.5)(embedding_tensor)
```